# Were the mother and uncle of Jaswinder Kaur Sidhu arrested?

Tags: history, law

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaswinder_Kaur_Sidhu) claims that the mother and uncle were arrested in the case of Jaswinder Kaur Sidhu. However, the [main link](http://www.theprovince.com/news/Charges+laid+historic+Jassi+Sidhu+homicide/5959874/story.html) given there is broken. Is there any alternate reliable source confirming this?

Comment: So your real question here is will someone else do the search for you?

Comment: The question is about the reliability of the claim which is posted on Wiki.. I found alternate sources which I do not believe. Posted one here. http://www.justiceforjassi.com/article/canadian-police-arrest-jassis-mother-and-uncle

Comment: The question would benefit from a bit more context. Furthermore, this seems to be pretty localised … I for one have never heard of this case, and there are a lot of cases of honour killing, meaning that this particular one doesn’t really stick out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

- [CBC News](http://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/british-columbia/story/2012/01/06/bc-jassi-sidhu-murder-arrests.html), Jan 6, 2012

> A B.C. woman and her brother have been arrested in connection with the 2000 slaying of the woman's daughter, Jassi Sidhu, and the attempted murder of the young woman's husband in India in what has been described as an honour killing.
>
> Malkit Kaur Sidhu, 63, the mother of victim Jassi Sidhu, was arrested Friday in the Vancouver suburb of Maple Ridge.

- [National Post](http://news.nationalpost.com/2012/01/09/accused-in-honour-killing-of-jaswinder-sidhu-to-get-bail-hearing/), Jan 9, 2012

> VANCOUVER • Wearing grey jailhouse sweats and grim expressions on their wrinkled faces, Malkit Kaur Sidhu and Surjit Singh Badesha made brief court appearances Monday, their first since their surprise arrests last week when local authorities announced their intention to see the pair extradited to India, where they are accused of playing a long-distance role in a notorious honour killing.